# Anything wrong with how I'm using node-mysql's pool.getConnection?

Tags: mysql, node.js

node-mysql's pool.getConnection looks like this when used:

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, callback) {
    callback(err, connection);
});
```

when used with exports.getConnection you type out:

```
var db = require('mysql');
var id = req.params.id;

db.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    if(err) throw err;
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id], function(err, data) {
        connection.release();
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(data);
    });    
});
```

I decided to abstract this out and in the mysql file I added:

```
exports.select = function(select, inserts, callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        connection.query(select, inserts, function(err, response){
            connection.release();
            callback(err, response);
        });
    }
}
```

this way when I want to do a query I type:

```
db.select('SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = ?', [id], function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(data);
});
```

I've tested this with and without inserts and with different queries. What I'm wondering is if there is anything dangerously wrong with it that I'm missing.

Comment: there is similar built in functionality already: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/blob/master/lib/Pool.js#L171

Comment: Right on. Well it was good practice at least.

Answer (score 0):

After Andrey Sidorov's comment I'm marking this as answered, not only because this is ok but it's not even necessary as the functionality is already built in. Thanks.